# Distinguishing between types of signs JS - circle area

Tags: javascript

How do I check if the given value is a special character or a letter?
And that it should return an error when specifying, for example: 1a or $1
For now, I made the '' if '' check if the radius is <= 0

```
let radius = prompt("write radius");
if(radius<=0){
  console.log("Incorrect data");
}
else{
console.log("area = " +area);
```

Comment: do you want to only allow valid numbers (positive ones) and reject any other input ?

Comment: exactly........

Comment: And do you have an input where the user types a value ? I recommend that you provide a [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

You may use a regular expression that checks if the user's input contains at least a non-digit character.
If the input has at least a no-digit char then you may show an error message, otherwise you may calculate the circle's area based on the typed radius (or whatever you need to do).

Here's a simple, live demo:

```js
const radius = prompt('Type a positive radius').trim();

alert(
  /** the regex check for at least one non-digit char */
  /\D/.test(radius) ?
  'Only positive numbers are allowed!' :
  'Circle area = ' + (Math.PI * radius * radius)
);
```

> The code above is intended as a minimal push in the right direction and it is not advised to be used in production unless some improvements and/or validations are added.

> The above demo only allows `integers` to be used, you may need to introduce some changes if you'd want to allow `float`s.

Answer (score 0):

`Number()` may be the function you are looking for, coupled with `Number.isNaN()`. Unlike `parseFloat()`, `Number()` will produce a `NaN` when not the entire string is a number:

```js
let examples = ["1", "1.1", "-.5", "a", "1$", "1a"];
for (let example of examples) {
  console.log(example,
              parseFloat(example),
              Number(example),
              Number.isNaN(Number(example)));
}
```

As you can see, `parseFloat()` does its best and gets `1` from `"1$"` and `"1a"`, but `Number()` refuses both.

So your checker code in particular could be something like:

```
let radius = Number(prompt("write radius"));
if (Number.isNaN(radius) || radius <= 0) {
  console.log("Incorrect data");
}
```